# Why the size differs? sizeof(a) vs sizeof(&a) of an array?

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

For the below code.

```
int a[4];
printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
printf("%d\n",sizeof(&a));
```

The output is

```
16
8
```

'a' represents the whole array (Also, the address of the first element of the array since it is a 1D array), and sizeof(a) represents the size of the whole array. Hence the size is 16. Understood.

'&a' represents the address of the whole array, and but sizeof(&a) represents what?

I guess its output came as 8 because the value is an address and calculating the size of a pointer which is fixed? Hence 8. Am I right?

But I still didn't get clarity.
Can anyone help to give a clear explanation?

Comment: You are right, so presumably don't need an explanation.

Comment: `but sizeof(&a) represents what?` -- The size of the address of the array, which is 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine.  Note that the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element.

Comment: @Dheeraj  "'a' represents .... (Also, the address of the first element of the array since it is a 1D array)," is a bit off. `a` sometimes convert to the type and value of the address of its first element, but that does not occur in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, they differ in type, and `sizeof` operator operates on the type.

First, `sizeof` operator yields a result of type `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

That said, in this case, `a` is the array (and this is one specific use case where array does not "decay"), so, it calculates the size as number of element multiplied by size of each element. In your case, the size of an `int` is supposed to be `4`, so you get `4*4`, `16`. For understanding, below print statements are similar:

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(a));
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(int[4])); // same as above
```

On the other hand, `&a` represents the address of the array, and that address is a pointer, of type `int (*)[4]`. Again, your system seems to use 8 bytes as pointer size, hence the output. To compare, we can write

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(&a));
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(int(*)[4])); // same as above
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `&a` returns a pointer to `a`.

A size of  <s>a</s>   the pointer in your system is `8` bytes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right, I should have used 'size of _the_ pointer'.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess its output came as 8 because the value is an address and calculating the size of a pointer which is fixed? Hence 8. Am I right?

Yes - the *expression* `&a` yields a pointer to `a`, which has type `int (*)[4]` (pointer to 4-element array of `int`).  On your system, that pointer type is 8 bytes wide.

So,

```
sizeof a  == sizeof (int [4])    == 16
sizeof &a == sizeof (int (*)[4]) == 8
sizeof *a == sizeof a[0] == sizeof (int) == 4
```

Different pointer types *may* have different sizes, but on most desktop and server systems all object pointers will be the same size (either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture).

Side note: `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - parentheses are only required if the operand is a type name.  It doesn't hurt anything to write `sizeof (a)` instead of `sizeof a` and I know some people here recommend it, but personally I tend not to.